# How to go to another activity from a simple ListView

Tags: android, listview

I made an app entitled "AndRoot!"

Hi! How can I go to activity named "ConditionsActivity" by clicking "App Developer's Concern" from my ListView

Here is my code for "TopicActivity"

```
package com.devcon.androot;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class TopicActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_topic);
        String[]  myStringArray={"App Developers' Concern","What is Root?","Pros of Rooted Device","Cons of Rooted Device",
                "How to Root","How Root can do that things?","Cheating and Hacking when Rooted?","Unrooted" +
                " vs. Rooted","Manufacturer vs. Root","Bring my warranty back!","How to Unroot","Do Unrooting" +
                " will bring my phone back to Original?","Credits"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter=new
                ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                myStringArray);
        ListView myList=(ListView)
                findViewById(R.id.listView);
        myList.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }



}
```

And Here is my content topic.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.devcon.androot.TopicActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_topic">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to set a listener for your list as

```
myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(this,ConditionsActivity.class);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below.

```
myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(TopicActivity.this, ConditionsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `OnItemClickListener` on `Listview` like this :

```
   // your code to set adaptor on Listview

   myList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // call intent here to move to another Activity on listview item click
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use an OnItemClickListener

```
myList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override 
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
    { 
        if (myStringArray[position].equals("App Developers' Concern") {
            Intent intent = new Intent(TopicActivity.this, ConditionsActivity.class);
            TopicActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an onItemClickListener for the listView to handle click event. Ive made some changes on your code. Please check.

```js
package com.devcon.androot;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class TopicActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_topic);
        String[]  myStringArray={"App Developers' Concern","What is Root?","Pros of Rooted Device","Cons of Rooted Device",
                "How to Root","How Root can do that things?","Cheating and Hacking when Rooted?","Unrooted" +
                " vs. Rooted","Manufacturer vs. Root","Bring my warranty back!","How to Unroot","Do Unrooting" +
                " will bring my phone back to Original?","Credits"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter=new
                ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                myStringArray);
        ListView myList=(ListView)
                findViewById(R.id.listView);

        myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){ 

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                switch(position) {
                    case 0:
                        startActivity(new Intent(TopicActivity.this,     ConditionsActivity.class);
                    break;
            }
        });
        myList.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an onItemClickListener to the ListView.
Here is how you do it:

```
            myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //Start new activity "YourSecondActivity"
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourSecondActivity.class);

                //Here you can send e.g. the items position by putting it as an extra into the intent
                int itemClicked = position;
                intent.putExtra("com.mycompany.myfirstapp.MESSAGE", itemClicked);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Btw: I don't think, that your question has anaything to do with javascript. You should remove this tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
myListview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(TopicActivity.this, ConditionsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.devcon.androot;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class TopicActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_topic);
        String[]  myStringArray={"App Developers' Concern","What is Root?","Pros of Rooted Device","Cons of Rooted Device",
                "How to Root","How Root can do that things?","Cheating and Hacking when Rooted?","Unrooted" +
                " vs. Rooted","Manufacturer vs. Root","Bring my warranty back!","How to Unroot","Do Unrooting" +
                " will bring my phone back to Original?","Credits"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter=new
                ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                myStringArray);
        ListView myList=(ListView)
                findViewById(R.id.listView);

        myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){ 

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                switch(position) {
                    case 0:
                        startActivity(new Intent(TopicActivity.this,     ConditionsActivity.class);
                    break;
            }
        });
        myList.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }



}
```